# Fill Up in VBA with Value from Below

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below to fill all blank cells in a selection with the value from above. I am trying to do the opposite, fill up based on the value below. I think I need to make it loop from the bottom of the selection but don't know how to do that. See below for the result I am going for.

```
 1   1
     2
 2   2
     3
     3
 3   3
```

```
Sub FillDown()

Dim columnValues  As Range, i As Long

Set columnValues = Selection

For i = 1 To columnValues.Rows.Count
    If columnValues.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
        columnValues.Cells(i, 1).Value = columnValues.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: iterate from the bottom up: `For i = columnValues.Rows.Count to 1 Step -1` and change the `columnValues.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value` to `columnValues.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate from the bottom up: `For i = columnValues.Rows.Count to 1 Step -1`

And change the `columnValues.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value` to `columnValues.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value`

```
Sub FillDown()

    Dim columnValues As Range
    Set columnValues = Selection
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = columnValues.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If columnValues.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
            columnValues.Cells(i, 1).Value = columnValues.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: I see where I copied wrong. This worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this slightly differently and populate ranges at a time rather than cells at a time:

```
Sub FillUp()
Dim CurrRow As Long, FillRow As Long, LastRow As Long
CurrRow = 1
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Do Until CurrRow >= LastRow
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & CurrRow + 1)) Then
        CurrRow = CurrRow + 1
    Else
        FillRow = Range("A" & CurrRow).End(xlDown).Row - 1
        Range("A" & CurrRow & ":A" & FillRow).Value = Range("A" & CurrRow).Value
        CurrRow = FillRow + 1
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Using the .end property of a cell reference will allow you to do that which means you are posting less times to the sheet, this will make a big difference in performance if there are large volumes of data or if there are many calculations in the sheet

Comment: If you're going to try to optimize, why not just do them all at once? See my answer for all updates done at once.

Comment: Still single point at a time just in an array as opposed to sheet, probably quicker than my method as done in memory rather than on the sheet and only posted once, nice one :). To the OP, I suggest you read and understand how all three of these solutions work because they all have valid benefits and can be useful to you in the future.

Comment: Thank you both! Appreciate the help and information.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Scott Craner already knows this but since an answer was posted making reference to optimize performance, I'm pretty sure this is the best approach.

```
Dim myArray(), i As Long

myArray = columnValues

    For i = UBound(myArray) - 1 To LBound(myArray, 1) Step -1
        
        If myArray(i, 1) = "" Then
            myArray(i, 1) = myArray(i + 1, 1)
        End If
    Next i
columnValues = myArray
```